# A project requires me to connect app to mongoDB, I keep having errors that points to a connection.js file in the node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The error detected in line 724 in the connection.js file in the node_modules folder   seem to be preventing me from connecting to my mongoDB cluster. How do I get around it.

> Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas
>   TypeError: callback is not a function

Please see Snapshot below.

[image]

Comment: Please never paste code and error messages that can be simply copied via clipboard as image.

Comment: Somewhere you’re supposed to pass a callback and aren’t.